# dateFromString returns nil. Unable to convert the date to the desired format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

This is my input nsstring  30/01/18 3:25 PM

I want the date in this format : 30/Jan/18 3:25 PM.

This is what i tried :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm "];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:releaseDate];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yy HH:mm "];
NSString *finalDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Also i tried this :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy HH:mm z"];
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:releaseDate];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yy HH:mm z"];
    NSString *finalDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

I am always getting date as nil !! What am i doing wrong?

Also : Time comes in both 12 hour format and 24 hour format. How do i handle both at the same time?

Comment: The date format does not match: 12 hour format is `hh` and `a` for AM/PM is missing. `z` stands for time zone, but there is none. Please read [Unicode.org - Date format patterns](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: One guy had given proper answer and removed it. I do not understand this behaviour in stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You check it below function, its working fine: -

```
-(void)DateChange
 {
    NSString *Input_Date =@"31/01/18 04:25 AM";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yy hh:mm a"];

    NSDate * Format_date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Input_Date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yy hh:mm a"];
    NSString *Change_date = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:Format_date];
    NSLog(@"Final Change Date :-  %@",Change_date);
}



My Output is :- 
Final Change Date :- 31/Jan/18 04:25 AM
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this function written in Swift to change the date format. Its working not

```
 func dateFormatterfromString(_ date: String!) -> String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:date)!
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:date)
    return dateString
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly for me on swift .

Comment: It cannot work with input string `30/01/18 3:25 PM` and it will never output the format `30/Jan/18 3:25 PM`